# Json Body Array validation in Postman using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I have Json response as below....

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": "XXXX",
      "source": ["pointer","value"],
      "detail": "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ."
    },
    {
      "status": "XXXX",
      "source": ["pointer","value"],
      "detail": "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ."
    },
    {
      "status": "XXXX",
      "source": ["pointer"],
      "title": " ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"
     }
  ]
}
```

I have to check weather Source is having Both Pointer and value in all the fields or not.
I tried some thing as below..

```
responseJson = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var list = responseBody.length;

tests["Expected fields"] = list === undefined || errors[0].source=== ["pointer","value"];
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Why do you not use `responseJson `?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this:

```js
var dataHaveIt = {
  "errors": [{
      "status": "XXXX",
      "source": ["pointer", "value"],
      "detail": "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ."
    },
    {
      "status": "XXXX",
      "source": ["pointer", "value"],
      "detail": "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ."
    }
  ]
};

var dataDontHaveIt = {
  "errors": [{
      "status": "XXXX",
      "source": ["pointer", "value"],
      "detail": "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ."
    },
    {
      "status": "XXXX",
      "source": ["pointer", "value"],
      "detail": "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ."
    },
    {
      "status": "XXXX",
      "source": ["pointer"],
      "title": " ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"
    }
  ]
};

var allHaveIt = false;
allHaveIt = dataHaveIt.errors.reduce(function(result, element) {
  return result && element.source.includes("pointer") && element.source.includes("value")
}, true);

console.log(allHaveIt);

allHaveIt = dataDontHaveIt.errors.reduce(function(result, element) {
  return result && element.source.includes("pointer") && element.source.includes("value")
}, true);

console.log(allHaveIt)
```

The actual work is done in this code:

```
allHaveIt = dataHaveIt.errors.reduce(function(result, element) {
  return result && element.source.includes("pointer") && element.source.includes("value")
}, true);
```

When passing as last parameter `true` to `reduce()` method we assume that all values exists, then `reduce()` will go through all elements and with the help of `includes()` we can check if the `source` property contains those elements